# Wine to run Windows application that has INPUT file

Tags: 14.04, wine, input

I am trying to run a Windows `*.exe` file on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have installed Wine. When I run the file, I need to specify the name of an input file.

In Windows, I would i) create a folder named `Temprture` in C:\ ii) create an environment variable and iii) here is how I would run the file in Windows:

```
C:\Users\UserName> cd..
C:\Users> cd..
C:\cd Temprture
C:\Temprture> z9fm8 G5889.INP
```

Now, in Wine, I i) created the folder in Wine's C:\ directory, ii) created an environment variable using `wine regedit` and then iii) I tried to run the file using:

```
wine "C:\Temprture\z9fm8 G5889.INP"
```

But I get an error message "No such file or folder".

How can I run this file in Wine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the working folder before start or start with a absolute path:

```
cd /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Temprture/; wine "/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Temprture/z9fm8 G5889.INP"
```

or

```
wine "C:\Temprture\z9fm8 C:\Temprture\G5889.INP"
```

or

```
wine start 'C:\Temprture\z9fm8 G5889.INP'
```

Comment: Are you sure you can `cd` with wine? I got `wine: cannot find 'cd C:\windows; notepad.exe'`, but the second solution works for me (`wine "C:\windows\notepad.exe"`).

Comment: Hi Helio: I tried both your approaches, but I am still getting the same error message: `wine: cannot find 'cd C:\Temprture; z9fm8 G5889.INP'`. The location where I placed the files is `/home/UserName/.wine/drive_c/Temprture`. With this in mind, should I use "drive C" instead of "C:\"?

Comment: Sorry, I said wrong, I'm not a frequent wine user. Try with `wine start 'C:\Temprture\z9fm8 G5889.INP'`

Comment: Did work all the methods explained in my question?

Comment: Hi, Helio, this method works: `wine start 'C:\Temprture\z9fm8 G5889.INP'`. Thank you for your help.